# Why does my color picker look so different from the one in the video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, color-picker

[This is the color picker in a video I'm watching.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdU3E.png)

[This is the how it looks like on my mac, it looks the same on my desktop PC...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agIiK.png)

I'm using the newest version of Chrome on both machines, why do they look so different?
How do I change the layout of the color picker?

I'm learning tag 'input' with type being color in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using the newest version of Chrome on both machines, why do they look so different?

There was a [recent effort to redo most of the input UI](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html) in Chromium-based browsers.

> How do I change the layout of the color picker?

You don't.  It's dependent on the system in use.  If you have a specific layout you must use, you must implement it yourself.  The standard inputs are meant to be controlled by the browser and the OS, so that they conform to the UI practices on the system in use.

Comment: I was just typing almost exactly this :) To add more specificity, the creator of the video was likely on OS X, maybe using Safari not Chrome, whereas I'm guessing @Sil Zec is on Windows or Linux

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I have a macbook pro and a desktop PC which runs win 10, I use newest Chrome on both of my machines, the first attached picture shows the color picker on a mac
Also, I don't think this is machine-dependent, because if it is, it should definitely look different in mac and in Win10, whereas they look exactly the same.

Comment: Just checked the link in your answer, is this the final version of the color picker now?
I mean the one in the first picture looks way better, and it has a lot more choices, sigh.